# Rust type visualization in VSCode does not work despite setting sourceLanguages

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust, lldb

Problem

I can't figure how to set up VSCode to properly visualize Rust types while debugging. Every variable is said to be of C type even though I added `"sourceLanguages": ["rust"]` to my launch.json.

My current setup

- rustc 1.31.0-nightly (bef62ccdd 2018-10-16)
- VSCode version: 1.28.2
- lldb version 6.0.1
- CodeLLDB version 1.0.0

Here is the launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "sourceLanguages": ["rust"],
            "name": "main",
            "program": "target/debug/chip8-emulator",
            "args": ["/home/alex/Downloads/chip8_roms/PONG"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there anything else I need to configure to make the visualization of types work correctly?